# how to solve java.exe was unexpected at this time when run logstash-8.3.2

Tags: java, logstash, exe

My Java environment is like this

- java version "11.0.14" 2022-01-18 LTS
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.14+8-LTS-263)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.14+8-LTS-263, mixed mode)

I also created LS_JAVA_HOME in System Variable

When I try to run logstash -f logstash.conf comment in cmd below error comes,

D:\Testing\2022\ELK (elastic logstash kibana)\logstash-8.3.2\bin>logstash -f logstash.conf

**\logstash-8.3.2\jdk\bin\java.exe was unexpected at this time.**

Please anyone can help me to solve this issue....

Comment: That error is typically an issue with paths, as indicated by the error it is only looking at `\logstash-8.3.2\jdk\bin\java.exe` the part of the path after the `)`. Try moving or installing the JDK to a file path that does not have parenthesis `(` or `)`

Comment: Thanks, My Issued has been fixed, when I removed parenthesis from the path.